# How to add a dynamic value to a Svelte store, based on values sourced from a HTML dropdown box on page

Tags: svelte

I'm playing around with Svelte code, as part of building a very simple shopping basket/store, and have an issue I can't resolve!

### Issue:

I want to update a specific property in an array of objects, that have been consumed in a Svelte writable store, but any change I make seems to be ignored!

### Background:

I have a Svelte writable store, defined as:

```
let products = writable(myjson.default);
```

This consists of 6 objects in an array, similar to this:

```
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Italian House Blend",
  "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac tellus finibus, molestie purus id, placerat augue. Sed in arcu placerat, ultricies nibh et, auctor dolor.",
  "image": "/images/1.png",
  "large_image": "/images/1_large.png",
  "price": 18,
  "quantity": 1,
  "variant": ""
},...
```

I'm looking to update the variant entry - this will be with one of three entries: Coarse, Fine, WholeBean. These are sourced from a drop-down within my product card component.

The values for the dropdown are sourced from this:

```
  let questions = [
    { id: 1, text: `Coarse` },
    { id: 2, text: `Fine` },
    { id: 3, text: `Whole Bean` }
  ];
```

... and I have a #each block that iterates through and correctly displays the text value on screen. The dropdown box is bound to allow two-way updates (this is done via a property called `selected`)

I have been able to console.log out the value of selected in my addToCart function - this displays the selected value:

```
const addToCart = (product) => {
    console.log("selected", selected)
    for (let item of $cart) {
      if(item.id === product.id) {
        product.quantity += 1
        product.variant = selected.text  <---- SOURCE OF PROBLEM??
        $cart = $cart;
        return;
      }
    }
    $cart = [...$cart, product]
    console.log("cart", $cart)
  }
```

The issue I have is I want to add the `selected.text` property to the array of objects, so I end up with this in console.log, and can then pipe out the variant property at a later stage:

```
cart 
[{…}]
0:
description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac tellus finibus, molestie purus id, placerat augue. Sed in arcu placerat, ultricies nibh et, auctor dolor."
id: 1
image: "/images/1.png"
large_image: "/images/1_large.png"
name: "Italian House Blend"
price: 18
quantity: 1
variant: "<<NAME APPEARS HERE>>"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I know I'm missing something obvious, but having spent 2 hours trying to figure it out, my head is hurting! Anyone able to help point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Could you add a REPL?

Comment: I've created a REPL - you can see it at https://svelte.dev/repl/6627f14b8efc4aa785d92b32fb45f6bc?version=3.38.2. It's a cut down version of my test site.

Comment: To replicate - click on Add to Cart in App.svelte - in the REPL console log, expand the cart entry. There is a variant property in the list, which is empty; this is the one I'm expecting to be replaced with the value from the drop-down field.

Answer (score 1):

If we inspect the `addToCart` function, notice that product's variant is only getting set if the product is already in the cart. If the product is not in the cart, then none of the code in that if block executes, meaning the variant is not set.

We can see that this is true by simply adding `product.variant = selected.text` just above `$cart = [...$cart, product]` like so:

```
const addToCart = (product) => {
  console.log("selected", selected)
  for (let item of $cart) {
    if(item.id === product.id) {
      product.quantity += 1
      product.variant = selected.text
      $cart = $cart;
      return;
    }
  }
  product.variant = selected.text  // ADDED LINE
  $cart = [...$cart, product]
  console.log("cart", $cart)
}
```

Comment: That makes sense now! Thankyou for explaining it - I suspect I've spent too many hours being too close to the code, and not seeing the wood for trees, so to speak ;-) Unfortunately it's shown up another problem I have to fix, with stores being destroyed on routing...but that's another story...